# Cannot write into ~/.m2 in docker maven container

Tags: bash, maven, docker

Why aren't files written in /root/.m2 in the maven3 docker image persistent during the build?

A simple dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8
RUN touch /root/.m2/testfilehere && ls -a /root/.m2
RUN  ls -a /root/.m2
CMD ["bash"]
```

Produces the following output.

```
$ docker build -t test --no-cache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM maven:3-jdk-8
 ---> 42e3884987fb
Step 2 : RUN touch /root/.m2/testfilehere && ls -a /root/.m2
 ---> Running in 1c1dc5e9f082
.
..
testfilehere
 ---> 3da352119c4d
Removing intermediate container 1c1dc5e9f082
Step 3 : RUN ls -a /root/.m2
 ---> Running in df506db8c1dd
.
..
 ---> d07cc155b20e
Removing intermediate container df506db8c1dd
Step 4 : RUN stat  /root/.m2/testfilehere
 ---> Running in af44f30aafe5
stat: cannot stat ‘/root/.m2/testfilehere’: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c stat  /root/.m2/testfilehere' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The file created at the first command is gone when the intermmediate container exists.

Also, this does not happen in the ubuntu image, just maven.

edit: using `ADD hostfile /root/.m2/containerfile` does work as a workaround, but is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `/root/.m2` is defined as a `VOLUME` in the image. When a container runs with a volume, the volume storage [is not part of the UnionFS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) - so its data is not stored in the container's writable layer:

> A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more containers that bypasses the Union File System.

The first `RUN` command creates a file in the volume, but that's in an **intermediary container** with its own volume. The file isn't saved to the image layer because it's in a volume.

The second `RUN` command is running in a **new intermediary container** which has its own volume. There's no content in the volume from the base image, so the volume is empty in the new container.

If you want to pre-populate the volume with data, you need to do it in the Dockerfile as you've seen.

Answer (score 2):

the maven docker image has an entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
```

On container started, entrypoint copy files from /usr/share/maven/ref into ${MAVEN_CONFIG} and erase your file

You can see script executed on startup by following this link

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/33eeccbb0ce15440f5ccebcd87040c6be2bf9e91/jdk-8/mvn-entrypoint.sh

Comment: The entrypoint should not be an issue. The erasure takes place before running the container, i.e., right after the Dockerfile command that did the file creation.

Comment: As explain in this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact
entrypoint is executed just before to run CMD /bin/bash

If you want to be sure, when you make ls seconde time, you can see copy_reference_file.log  settings-docker.xml
They are copied from maven ref directory

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation for this in Docker Maven:
https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven#packaging-a-local-repository-with-the-image

```
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
```

After you run your Docker image, the `settings.xml` will appear in `/root/.m2`.